# React Google Map Fitbounds not a function error

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps, react-google-maps-api

Whenever I use map.fitbound I get a Uncaught TypeError: map.fitBounds is not a function.

The important code snippet:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
const map = useRef(null);

const getMarkers = (inPins) => {
    return inPins.map((pin, pinInd) => {
            bounds.extend(pin.position);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            return <Marker {...pin} key={pinInd} />
    })
}

return (
        <GoogleMap
            ref={map}
            mapContainerStyle={mapStyles}
            defaultZoom={zoom}
            center={center}
        >
            {getMarkers(pins)}
        </GoogleMap>
        )
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong. The bounds variable seems to be working fine with the positions, it's just that the map somehow does not have the fitbound function even though google map should should have it and it's been referenced in a lot of tutorials. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `map.current.fitBounds(bounds)`?

Answer (score 1):

> When the ref attribute is used on a custom class component, the ref object receives the mounted instance of the component as its `current`. [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs)

`map` isn't an instance of a `google.maps.Map`. It is actually, a React ref and needs to be accessed via `.current`. You probably also want to check if `map.current` is defined before usage.

```js
if (map.current) {
  map.current.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Since this is confusing, it might make sense to rename the ref from `map` to `mapRef` or similar.